# Combining several articles using combine package causes errors

Tags: combine

For my thesis I need to combine two articles into one document. I have looked at the [`combine` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) which looks perfect for this. However, when I try to typeset my document, I get a lot of errors:

```
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@minilofdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@minilotdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@partlofdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@partlotdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@sectlofdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \c@sectlotdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtc@savelofdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtc@restorelofdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtchideinmainlof already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtc@savelotdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtc@restorelotdepth already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 LaTeX Error: Command \mtchideinmainlot already defined.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 Undefined control sequence.
Latex Error: ./main.tex:81 Undefined control sequence.
```

(`main.tex` is my first article. It makes similar complaints about my other article)

The undefined control sequence it complains about is `\begin{document}.`

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a *MWE*, that is, the smallest document you can create that reproduces the problem. That way, it's much easier for others to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As suggested by gerrit, without a fully [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem it is going to be difficult to determine your exact issue.

Comment: When making a MWE, please put on the top of your document, before `\documentclass`, the command `\listfiles`.  This puts in the log the list of packages (and other files) used and their versions.  Please post this list along with your MWE.